# Insertar datos en 2 tablas diferentes de mysql desde Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans, insert

tengo el siguiente método, que ocurre al presionar un botón "Imprimir factura"

```
private void btnimpActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        String idfactura=nro_fac.getText();
        String moneda=combomoneda.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String fecha=txtfecha.getText();
        String condic=combocond.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String mediopago=combomediopago.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String preciototal=txttotal.getText();
        String idcliente=txtdnicv.getText();
        String sql="INSERT INTO factura VALUES ("+idfactura+",'"+moneda+"','"+fecha+"','"+condic+"','"+mediopago+"','"+preciototal+"',"+idcliente+")";
        if(c.insertar(sql)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Factura guardada!!");
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al guardar");
        }
        String codprod=txtcod.getText();
        String cantprod=txtcant.getText();
        String sql1="INSERT INTO detalle_factura VALUES ("+idfactura+","+codprod+","+cantprod+")";
    }
```

Necesito que inserte valores en 2 tablas diferentes en mysql.

Al cambiar el nombre del String sql a String sql1 en la segunda consulta ya no ejecuta la misma

El método para insertar datos en la base de datos es el siguiente:

```
public boolean insertar(String sql){
    try {
        Statement sentencia;
        sentencia=con.createStatement();
        sentencia.executeUpdate(sql);
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Alguien sabe cuál podría ser la solución? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Para que la inserción ocurra tienes que pasar `sql1` al método `insertar`, algo parecido a lo que haces con `sql`.

Para no mostrar dos veces la interfaz gráfica, puedes recoger en una variable el resultado de ambas llamadas y mostrar el mensaje una sola vez. Algo así:

```
private void btnimpActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        String idfactura=nro_fac.getText();
        String moneda=combomoneda.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String fecha=txtfecha.getText();
        String condic=combocond.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String mediopago=combomediopago.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String preciototal=txttotal.getText();
        String idcliente=txtdnicv.getText();
        String sql="INSERT INTO factura VALUES ("+idfactura+",'"+moneda+"','"+fecha+"','"+condic+"','"+mediopago+"','"+preciototal+"',"+idcliente+")";

        //Declaramos un StringBuilder para ir concatenando mensajes
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");

        //Hacemos la asignación con un ternario
        sb.append(c.insertar(sql) ? "Factura guardada!!" : "Error al guardar factura");
        sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        String codprod=txtcod.getText();
        String cantprod=txtcant.getText();
        String sql1="INSERT INTO detalle_factura VALUES ("+idfactura+","+codprod+","+cantprod+")";

        sb.append(c.insertar(sql1) ? "Detalle guardado!!" : "Error al guardar detalle");

        //Mostramos todos los mensajes del sb una sola vez
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString());
    }
```

#### Advertencia sobre la seguridad

Tus consultas son altamente vulnerables a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Para prevenir este riesgo deberías usar consultas preparadas.

Answer (score 0):

No estas ejecutando la segunda sentencia sql1, debes llamar nuevamente al método de insertar pero con la sentencia sql1, quedaria algo así
if(c.insertar(***sql1***)){...

Ahora como sugerencia quizá sea mejor crear un procedimiento almacenado en la base de datos que te reciba todos los parámetros y ahí realices ambos insert.

Saludos.